# How do I iterate over array of id's and push an axios response from each iteration to a new array (MERN)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, iteration

I thought my code was good but I keep getting 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' from my server.

The array of id's is coming from local storage and is successfully stored in my state (React).

I have tried to look for a solution to this already but nothing seems to get rid of the error message above.

Response in Postman works perfectly fine but seems to be an issue with multiple axios requests.

Data array remains empty and nothing logs to the console.

My current code is below;

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    getFavourites();

  },[]);

  async function getFavourites() {
      let arr = [];
      
      
        for(let i=0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
          let key = localStorage.key(i);
          let value = localStorage[key];
          if(value == 'true' ){
              arr.push(key)
          }; 
          setUsers(arr);
      };

      let data = [];
      for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        data.push(axios.get(`${domain}/search/${users[i]}`))
      }
      
      Promise.all(data)
        .then(responses => console.log(responses));


};
```

Backend router

```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {

    await Service.find({_id: req.params.id})
        .then(profile => res.json(profile))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));

});
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please provide a complete reproducible code.

Comment: Your error, is it on the server or the front-end? if its on the server, why are you sharing the front-end code? This error usually occurs in ExpressJS when you try to res.send() or res.json() more than once in a single request. So, add `return res.send()` or `return res.json()` in the controller for the required route. This way, the function returns immediately after you've set your response. So, it only happens once. Also, make sure to add return before the first res and not the subsequent ones.

Comment: Can you add the Backend code, it seems you are sending the response more than once.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the backend router now